# Entity Framework 4, TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) and annotation

Tags: entity-framework-4, data-annotations

I currently try to migrate an application of mine from datasets to EF4.
So I have an existing database. One of the tables is mapped to 2 classes, depending of the value of a column.
So I am in a TBH schema with an existing table and an existing discriminator.
Is there a way to discribe this using annotations ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. TPH discriminator can be controlled only through Fluent-API.

Comment: :( Thanks for answering. That's why I didn't see anything about such a functionnality !