# How to implement TPH mapping with Entity Framework attributes only

Tags: entity-framework, orm, data-annotations, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.3

I need to map a legacy db table to a polymorphic hierarchy using Entity Framework Code First.  Unfortunately, I have some ridiculous constraints, and I'm not sure if it is possible.  These constraints require that:

1. I cannot define mappings with the fluent interface.  I have to use the Entity Framework mapping attributes.
2. I cannot add custom conventions to the `DbModelBuilder`.
3. I cannot modify the table structure.

Is there anyway to accomplish this directly with EF?  If not, then what is my best bet for working with such a table?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you will have is that doing more complex things (like defining the discriminator in Code-First TPH) will require fluent. Perhaps someone else can comment with additional detail? This guy got the same answer but still no citation: [Entity Framework 4, TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) and annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014410/entity-framework-4-tph-table-per-hierarchy-and-annotation)

Depending on how you are going to use this data (is this read only?) I think you have lots of options for loading it and interacting with it. You just have to do the extra work to map objects onto their classes after pulling the entire record from the table instead of having EF do it all for you...

Again, someone else may have a better suggestion.